# How to perform a nested list comprehension with a break?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have a large DataFrame of distances that I want to classify.

```
df_norms = pd.DataFrame([[0, 100, 200, 4000000]], 
                        columns=['mode', 'min', 'medium', 'max'])

df_afst = pd.DataFrame([[0, 50, -1],
                        [0, 150, -1],
                        [0, 0, -1],
                        [0, 250, -1]], 
                       columns = ['train', 'station', 'bbh'])
```

The norms DataFrame says that for item zero, each distance <= 100 is classified as 0, next when is is <= 200 it is 1 and finally the catch-all <= a large number it is 2.

This is very easy to do with `for`-loops. Example:

```
for i in [0]: # 1 element list just for the example
    bbh_id = i + 2
    mode = df_afst.iloc[0, i]
    for iy, y in enumerate(df_afst[df_afst.columns[i+1]].values):
        for ix, x in enumerate(df_norms.iloc[mode]):
            if x > y:
                df_afst.loc[iy, df_afst.columns[bbh_id]] = ix - 1
                break
```

Before:

```
   train  station  bbh
0      0       50   -1
1      0      150   -1
2      0        0   -1
3      0      250   -1
```

and after

```
   train  station  bbh
0      0       50    0
1      0      150    1
2      0        0    0
3      0      250    2
```

I want to do this in a list comprehension and have no idea how to do this: the `break` makes it hard to do. The best I can do is:

```
for i in [0]:
    bbh_id = i + 2
    mode = df_afst.iloc[0, i]
    r = [ix - 1 for iy, y in enumerate(df_afst[df_afst.columns[i+1]].values)
                     for ix, x in enumerate(df_norms.iloc[mode])
                         if x > y]

 # results in : [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2]
```

As you can see the result is kind of correct if you split the result:

```
[0, 1, 2 | 1, 2 | 0, 1, 2 | 2]
```

I just need the first of the sublist, don't know how. I cannot simulate the `break`. Tried min, `[any][1]` and next but just can't get it right. Somebody any ideas?

**Update**

I was rightly corrected by @chepner that my example was inconsistent. Sorry for that. @Thierry Lathuille remarked correctly that list comprehensions are not always the right tool. He's quite right on that point and because I don't know when or not they are the right tool is the reason I want to find out how that works in this case.

The two answers I got on this answer were enlightening to me. I never heard of pandas cut and had never bothered with numpy argwhere.

I made a small benchmark out of curiosity.

```
print('\n*** pd.cut')
cpu = time.time()
cuts = df_norms.iloc[0].tolist()
bbh3 = pd.cut(df_afst['station'], cuts, labels=False, include_lowest=True)
df_afst['bbh'] = bbh3
print('CPU {:.4f} seconds'.format(time.time() - cpu))
    
print('\n*** Using numpy and its functions')
cpu = time.time()
bbh2 = [np.min(np.argwhere(np.less(td, df_norms.values.ravel()))-1) for td in df_afst.station.values]
df_afst['bbh'] = bbh2
print('CPU {:.4f} seconds'.format(time.time() - cpu))

print('\n*** Simple loop')                
cpu = time.time()
for i in [0]:
    bbh_id = i + 2
    mode = df_afst.iloc[0, i]
    for iy, y in enumerate(df_afst[df_afst.columns[i+1]].values):
        for ix, x in enumerate(df_norms.iloc[mode]):
            if x > y:
                df_afst.loc[iy, df_afst.columns[bbh_id]] = ix - 1
                break

print('CPU {:.4f} seconds'.format(time.time() - cpu))

print('\n*** Wrong approach')                
cpu = time.time()
for i in [0]:
    bbh_id = i + 2
    mode = df_afst.iloc[0, i]
    r = [ix - 1 for iy, y in enumerate(df_afst[df_afst.columns[i+1]].values)
                     for ix, x in enumerate(df_norms.iloc[mode])
                         if x > y]
print('CPU {:.4f} seconds'.format(time.time() - cpu))
```

I enlarged the dataset from 4 in the example to 2,000,000, close to my dataset of 10,000,000. The results I got were interesting:

```
*** pd.cut
CPU 0.0131 seconds

*** Using numpy and its functions
CPU 29.4257 seconds

*** Simple loop
CPU 214.5378 seconds

*** Wrong approach
CPU 103.5768 seconds
```

The speedup with the pandas cut function is hardly to believe. I double checked the results but it reallyseems ok.

Two answers, both correct and very insightful. I decided to mark the answer of @carlos melus as the correct one because he comes closest to the list comprehension I requested.

Comment: For starters, list comprehensions create lists, not data frames. It's not just alternate syntax for a `for` loop.

Comment: And list comprehensions are not meant to be a better replacement for `for` loops. They are convenient in some cases, but trying to use them outside of these cases is mostly counterproductive.

Comment: @chepner, my bad, I did assign to the DataFrame at first but that, understandably, crashed. Foprgot to adjust the example, just try to look at the numbers.

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille, my experience is that they usually (not always, that's true) are a better replacement than for's in speed. Orders of magnitude are normal. Just wanted to try it for this case.

Comment: If you are seeing orders of magnitude difference, your `for` loops were either wildly inefficient or doing something different from what the list comprehension actually does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorize the calculation using numpy:

```
[np.min(np.argwhere(np.less(td, df_norms.values.ravel()))-1) for td in df_afst.station.values]
```

np.less compares each distance in df_afst.station with all the values from df_norms and returns a boolean matrix, with a True value if `td` is less than the corresponding value in df_norms.

For example, np.less(50, [0, 100, 200, 4000000]) returns: array([False,  True,  True,  True])

Using np.argwhere, we extract the indices of the True values in the output array, starting at 1, so we subtract that 1 to make it start at 0.
From there, get the minimum index that is True in the array, which is the value you are looking for.

You can run all of this in a list comprehension, and the result will be: [0, 1, 0, 2]

Answer (score 1):

You would greatly benefit from using [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

Assuming that you want to bin the values in `df_afst['station']` (which is not entirely clear from the question, but I am guessing based on the example), you could do:

```py
cuts = df_norms.iloc[0].tolist()
bbh = pd.cut(df_afst['station'], cuts, labels=False, include_lowest=True)
```

or more directly:

```py
bbh = pd.cut(df_afst['station'], [-1, 100, 200, float('inf')], labels=False)
```

Outcome:

```py
>>> bbh
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    2
Name: station, dtype: int64
```

Of course, you can instead assign this to a column.

This will be orders of magnitude faster than Python loops (either explicit or as comprehensions).

Comment: I certainly benefit from this function. the speedup is unbelievable. Thank you for bringing it to my attention.